# use np.apply_along_axis on a function with multiple arguments

Tags: python, numpy

I want to apply a method on all rows of a matrix and then get the average of the results.

Concretely, let's say I have a method:

```
import numpy as np
def relu(x, grad=False):
    numpy_x= np.array(x)
    if grad:
        return np.where(numpy_x <= 0, 0, 1)
    return np.maximum(0, numpy_x)
```

I have an numpy array:

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
```

I want to apply relu to all rows of the array and sum them up. So I tried to do the following to first apply relu to all rows:

```
np.apply_along_axis(relu, 1,a)
```

However, there is a problem, we can apply relu with param grad=False to all rows only. What if we want to apply relu(,grad=True) to all rows of a?

Comment: Write a cover function that sets the `grad` parameter (a new `def` or a `partial`).  But for a simple case of iterating on rows of a 2d array, an explicit for loop is just as good.  `apply_along_axis` is Python code and doesn't improve speed.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying a little bit what is the problem? Is it about the default argument? Also, why do you need `np.apply_along_axis`? `relu(a)` achieves the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand your problem. Is it about the default argument? If so, try

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: relu(x, grad=True), 1, a)
```

### Edit

If you want to average the results, I believe that the following code is enough:

```
avg_relu = np.mean(relu(a, False), axis=1)
avg_relu_grad = np.mean(relu(a, True), axis=1)
```